# Delete multiple rows in MySql without CTE

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have got a database with about 7000 cars, but unfortunately, only about 1000 are unique. Can I delete all the duplicated rows?

The schema looks like this:

[image: this:]

Thank you!

Comment: Some good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
delete t1
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2
    on  t2.brand = t1.brand
    and t2.model = t1.model
    and t2.id < t1.id
```

This will delete duplicates on `(brand, model)` while retaining the one with the smallest id.

Comment: Almost, but it deletet also more than it should, because now, there is nor Chevrolet Corvett anymore....https://justpaste.it/4lvpj

Comment: @Tamiond: I would doubt that. What if you run `select * from mytable where brand = 'Chevrolet' and model = 'Corvette'`?

Comment: I also tested this and it works. I suspect Tamiond did not run the same query.

Comment: Thanks, i just didn't spot it :/

Comment: Welcome @Tamiond, no pb!